# Trouble updating new column after adding it

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Given the following SQL:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE name = 'NewFieldName' AND object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.MyTableName'))
    RETURN

-- Add NewFieldName column to part of the Summer 2012 release cycle.
ALTER TABLE dbo.[MyTableName] ADD
    [NewFieldName] SmallINT NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT DF_MyTableName_NewFieldName DEFAULT (2)

UPDATE [MyTableName] SET NewFieldName = 1 WHERE [Name] = 'FindMe' --Update one specific value
```

Produces the following error message:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 10 Invalid column name
>   'NewFieldName'.

I'm sure I'm missing something basic, but trying to put "GO" after the alter makes the UPDATE run everytime and I don't want to do that.

How can I structure this statement so that it will check to see if the column exists and, if it doesn't add it and then set the values as stated in my UPDATE statements?

Comment: first update statement is redundant, you set all records to 2 by `default (2)`

Comment: The above statements worked for me. How are you executing them? Is the column `NewFieldName` created?

Comment: @AmirIsmail  wrong.  When I run ALTER statement, field is created but default is not set for existing records. Maybe there's a different way to write ALTER to do that; but current structure does not set default values for existing rows.

Comment: @juergend It worked for me initially, but now I'm getting that error...probably to do with something Martin is saying.  Trying to pinpoint the issue.

Comment: @ray023 you are right, you can declare this columns as `not allow null`, by that old columns will be set to default value.

Comment: @ray023 - When it worked initially probably the table didn't exist so all statements that referenced it were subject to deferred compile.

Comment: @AmirIsmail Null value not valid so I do need NOT NULL in there.  Statement updated.  ty.

Comment: Just take note that adding a column with not null / default is not an online operation, meaning it will have to write to every row in the table and this can affect your other users. In SQL Server 2012 with Enterprise Edition you *can* perform this operation online.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need the statement referencing the new column to be compiled after the new column is added. One way of doing this is to run it as a child batch with `EXEC`.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM   sys.columns 
               WHERE  name = 'NewFieldName' 
                      AND object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.MyTableName')) 
BEGIN
  -- Add NewFieldName column to part of the Summer 2012 release cycle. 
  ALTER TABLE dbo.[MyTableName] 
           ADD [NewFieldName] SMALLINT NOT NULL 
           CONSTRAINT DF_MyTableName_NewFieldName DEFAULT (2) 

  EXEC(' UPDATE [MyTableName] SET NewFieldName = 1 WHERE [Name] = ''FindMe''') 
END
```

The reason it worked for you originally is presumably because the table itself did not exist when the batch was compiled thus meaning that all statements in it referencing the table are subject to deferred compile.